# Redirect templates with native template routes

Tags: routing

I have a template group called 'members' with two templates - 'male' and 'female'.

Now, I want the 'index'-template of the 'members'-group to redirect to the 'male'-template, whenever somebody types in the following URL:

`my_site.com/members`

I've setup a route in the CP like this...

`'members/index' => 'members/male'`

... and put this in my 'members/index'-template:

`{route="members/male"}`

I expected this to initiate a redirect, but it doesn't. So, how do the new native template routes actually work?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've just discovered the following feature in the access-section of the template manager:

"When unauthorized users try to access this page, show this one instead"

This solves my problem perfectly!

Or, as an alternative, I can add this to the `members/index` template:

```
{if segment_2 != ""}
    {redirect="members/male"}
{/if}
```

Comment: Also, the route tag doesn't do any redirecting, it is for determining the route that is set for a particular template group and name, with optional parameters. ref : https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/template_routes.html#segment-variables-and-paths